# Android Key Hash

Tags: android

I have generated key hash for Single Sign on In facebook.... I wanna to know that whether there is any way to check that the generated key is Correct or not.. Because Single sign on is Not working for me..

Comment: This is a very vague question - is this for oauth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to check key hash is correct or not,
But while generating key one can do mistake and give incorrect alias name or incorrect password, keytool do not alert you about either of this which leads you to incorrect key hash. when you input this key to facebook it will then say invalid_key.
You can regerate key to cross verify is it correct or not, check on different operating systems(For some people there is problem generating key hash on windo)